# Can I use inverse inequality for an infinite space, $H^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Let $u \in H^1(\Omega)$ and $Q_0 u$ is a $L^2$ projection of $u$ to a polynomial finite space $P_k(T)$ where $T \in \mathcal{T}_h$ is a finite element and $\mathcal{T}_h$ is a set of all the elements.
Can I combine two terms by using inverse inequality as below:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|Q_0 u - u \|_{\partial T} &\le& C(\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} h ^{-1} \| Q_0 u - u \|_T ^2  + \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} h \| \nabla ( Q_0 - u)\|_T ^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\ 
&\le& C(\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h}h \| \nabla ( Q_0 - u)\|_T ^2)^{\frac{1}{2}} \\
&\le& Ch^k \| u \|_{k+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
I used trace inequality to a boundary term and try to use an inverse inequality to bound my error.  Is this correct?  If it is not, can someone explain to me why not?
Thanks
Anna

Comment: You can enclose math formulas in dollar signs here, just like in TeX.

Comment: @amzoti, amwhy: seriously, why did you accept this edit without even improving it?

Comment: I edited your post to render the equations properly, but I'm not sure if I did that correctly, you may want to check that. I'm not sure what the sum is running over...

Comment: Hi, this is a specific question about approximation property of subspace of Sobolev spaces, which lies in the realm of numerical methods for pde, so the appropriate tags are [tag:pde], [tag:numerical-methods], and [tag:functional-analysis]. The tag [tag:analysis] is way too broad.

Comment: @user86937: I'm not a girl, but you're welcome. ;) On a different note, you should use \lVert and \rVert instead of \|, or you'll get the wrong spacing. Also, try to use bigger brackets when the standard ones are too small.

Comment: Oops! Thank you again!

Comment: Your explanation definitely helped me to understand better about the boundary term error estimates.  Thank you Shuha Cao for your time and help!

Comment: @user86937 No problem, don't forget to upvote and accept (if you think the answer helped). If you don't know how to do it, look at here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer This is the Math Stackexchange way of saying thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The magnitude of your final estimate does not look correct.

Rule of thumb: the approximation property loses $1/2$ when moving to the boundary because of the regularity decreasing of $1/2$ for the function $u$.

Let's say $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^2$:
$$
\|Qu - u\|_{0,\partial T} \lesssim h^{1/2}\|u\|_{\frac12,\partial T} 
\lesssim h^{1/2}|u|_{1, T}. 
$$ 
Then you lose another order of $h$ when you consider the $L^1$-sum of $\|Qu - u\|_{\partial T}$. If we follow what you did in the question, the estimate should be something like
$$
\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|Q u - u \|_{0,\partial T}  \lesssim \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|Q u - u \|_{0, T}^{1/2} \|Q u - u \|_{1, T}^{1/2} 
\\
\lesssim  \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \left(h^{-1} \|Q u - u \|_{0, T} + h\|Q u - u \|_{1, T}\right) ,
$$
which will not give you an $h$ in front of the final estimate if finally you wanna use $W^{k,2}$-norm ($H^k$-norm) on the whole domain.

But if it is $L^2$-sum, the standard argument is:
$$
\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|Q u - u \|_{0,\partial T}^2 \lesssim \sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h} \|Q u - u \|_{0, T} \|Q u - u \|_{1, T} 
\\
\lesssim  \left(\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h}  \|Q u - u \|_{0, T}^2\right)^{1/2}  \left(\sum_{T \in \mathcal{T}_h}  \|Q u - u \|_{1, T}^2\right)^{1/2} \lesssim h |u|_{1,\Omega}^2.
$$
Take square root of both sides you will see that missing $h^{1/2}$ in the estimate vs the interior estimate in each element. Above is just the standard result of $L^2$-projection's approximation property, for example [this widely cited paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1991-56-194/S0025-5718-1991-1066830-3/S0025-5718-1991-1066830-3.pdf) in the finite element community.

Last thing is that what you used is not the inverse inequality either, the inverse inequality applies only on polynomial space, and it is bounding the $H^{k+1}$-norm by a lower order norm, for example
$$
|Qu|_{1,T} \leq h^{-1} \|Qu\|_{0,T},
$$
it is called "inverse" because normally by Poincaré type inequality, the estimate is the other way around.

Comment: I have another question.

Comment: @ShuhaoCao Excuse me, but I don't see any condition $h \leq 1$ when you write the inverse inequality. May I ask why? I'm having basically the same question of the OP

Comment: @bobinthebox The inequality is normally used in the process of letting $h\to 0$, i.e., the mesh is finer and finer. For example, in proving certain convergence, so normally $h< 1$ is automatically implied.